# The link you have used to enter the PayPal system is invalid. Please review the link and try again

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I'm trying to test a paypal form through the sandbox, and have created a preconfigured test account.

However, when I go through my paypal form and enter the password I am proceeded with this error:

**"The link you have used to enter the PayPal system is invalid. Please review the link and try again."**

I am unsure what this error means. I removed my email address I am aware it shows as xxxxxxxx@gmail.com in the example below.

My form is below:

```
<form name "_xclick" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

SteamID: <input type="text" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $steamid;?>" size="45">
<br> <?php echo $possible;?>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Seriouspants Donation <?php echo $steamid;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="xxxxxxxx@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://seriouspants.net/customs/paypal/complete.php">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="5.00">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Comment: Double check your business email address, this error may occur due to invalid business email.

Answer (score 4):

The payment email for receiving payment might be on a personal account. Upgrade it to Business account. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I hadn't checked my business account.
To get the email sent with code for the test account, you need to access to notifications (https://developer.paypal.com/developer/notifications/)

Answer (score -1):

You needs to create seperate Sandbox account in https://developer.paypal.com (not in the sandbox.paypal.com) where you can create multiple test account inside with fake balance.